# Moving an object over array grid in C

Tags: c, arrays

I created this program which places an object on a grid. The final program should takes input from the keyboard and move the object around the grid, right now i'm only making some test to see if i can move it.

The object is placed randomly using `srand`, i'm testing the function `moveUp`too see whether or not the object `R`is moved, but it's not moving yet.

Example:

```
  - - -                                             - - R
  - R -  After moveUp is executed, it should be ->  - - -                                                
  - - -                                             - - -
```

Since [1][1] will lead to [2][2].

The object R, though, it's not moving, i think that the trouble is to edit the coords `a` and `b`, since both of them should be upgraded by moveUp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X 3
#define Y 3

// Print the array
char printArray(char row[][Y], size_t one, size_t two)
{
   // output column heads
   printf("%s", "       [0]  [1]  [2]");
   // output the row in tabular format
   for (size_t i = 0; i < one; ++i) {
      // output label for row
      printf("\nrow[%lu] ", i);
      // output grades for one student
      for (size_t j = 0; j < two; ++j) {
         printf("%-5c", row[i][j]);
      } 
   } 
} 

int moveUp(int o, int t);


int main(void)
{  

   // initialize student grades for three students (rows)
   char row[X][Y] =  
      { { '-', '-', '-'},
        { '-', '-', '-'},
        { '-', '-', '-'} };

   int a, b;
   srand(time(NULL));


   a = (rand() % 3);
   b = (rand() % 3);


   // output the row
   char robot = row[a][b] = 'X';

   puts("The array is:");
   printArray(row, X, Y);
   printf("\n");



   a, b = moveUp(a, b);
   printArray(row, X, Y);
   /*
   while(h != '3'){


    switch (h) {


      case '1': 
        printArray(row, X, Y);
        break;

      case 'N':
        moveUp(a, b);
        printArray(row, X, Y);
        break;
    }
    scanf("%s", &h);

  }
  */

}

int moveUp(int o, int t)
{
  ++o;
  ++t;

  return o;
  return t;

}
```

Comment: `return o;  return t;` -- You can't return two values like that from a function. You can return a `struct` containing two values, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nut sure what are you trying to do , but this might work :

```
void moveUp(char row[][Y],int * o, int * t)
{
    row[*o][*t] = '-';
    if(*o < X - 1)
        *o++;
    if(*t < Y - 1)
        *t++;
    row[*o][*t] = 'X';
}
```

And then use it :

```
moveUp(row,&a,&b)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I got main.c:56:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘moveUp’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    moveUp(row,&a,&b);

Comment: I think the error is when i pass the array to the function

Comment: Hmm, then try this way @Sile

Comment: This time it compiled but moveUp got core dump!

Comment: @Sile Mmm, maybe now ? You need to debug to tell me what isn't working ..

Comment: Basically it compiles, but sometimes the program executes normally and sometimes it goes on segmentation fault, i have no idea why

Comment: You'll have to debug and tell me exactly when it throws the error.. It hard to know why this is happening :)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try!